# Component Error with bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native

I have been retooling my approach to an app that I have made, started using classes and more object oriented style and separate files for pages and not just smacking everything in a function in the main file.

Here is the App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import {homeScreen} from './Screens/Home';
import {addAsset} from './Screens/AddAsset';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <View>

      <Text>Yeet</Text>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={homeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Add" component={addAsset} />
        </Tab.Navigator> 
      </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and here is a sample screen that I am trying to display

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';






class homeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>Main Page</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  export default homeScreen;
```

I keep getting an error saying that it cant find a component or get component prop for the home screen.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Still kind of new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done a default export so you should import like below which results in an undefined being passed to the tab navigation and causes the error

```
import homeScreen from './Screens/Home';
```

Removing the curly braced would fix the issue.

Another suggestion is start component name with Capitals like HomeScreen